# Evaluating Spring @Value annotation as primitive boolean

Tags: spring, annotations

I have a Spring `@Configuration` annotated class, `MappingsClientConfig`, with a boolean field as:

```
 @Value("${mappings.enabled:true}")
 private boolean mappingsEnabled;
```

This class is imported into another Spring annotated class like so :

```
@Configuration
@Import(MappingsClientConfig.class)
public class LookupManagerConfig {
```

When instantiating the class via Spring context in a test-case, the container is unable to parse the string into the boolean field `mappingsEnabled` and I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private boolean com.barcap.tcw.mappings.economic.client.config.EconomicMappingsClientConfig.economicMappingsEnabled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${mappings.enabled:true}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 138 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${mappings.enabled:true}]
    at org.springframework.beans.SimpleTypeConverter.convertIfNecessary(SimpleTypeConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.SimpleTypeConverter.convertIfNecessary(SimpleTypeConverter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${mappings.enabled:true}]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.SimpleTypeConverter.convertIfNecessary(SimpleTypeConverter.java:49)
    ... 144 more
```

Any leads as to what am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the fact that you are not loading the properties file where you defined `mappings.enabled`, but i can't be sure without more details.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Its an old thread but if you still want to inject Non-String values using @Value Spring annotation, do this:

```
@Value("#{new Boolean('${item.priceFactor}')}")
private Boolean itemFactorBoolean;

@Value("#{new Integer('${item.priceFactor}')}")
private Integer itemFactorInteger;
```

Works for me on Spring boot 1.5.9 with Java 8.

Comment: spring 4.3 has setTrimValues() in <context:property-placeholder>. For spring < 4.3 can manually trim() it to prevent `"xx = true "` become false.  `@Value("#{new Boolean('${xx}'.trim())}")`

Comment: Best described here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: Works with Spring Boot 2.x as well.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're missing the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. You need to register it as a bean factory post processor. Theoretically this could be done like this:

```
public class PostProcessorConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessor getPP() {
       PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
       configurer.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("/my.properties")});
       return configurer;
    }
}
```

However, there seems to be a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8269) that causes other issues doing this from a java based configuration. See ticket for workarounds.

Comment: Adding the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer did the trick. But initially when I tried to define a new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, I was getting errors for missing placeholders that worked fine before. As if defining the new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer was overriding some existing behaviour. 

So for now, I have defined a new PPC and added all my properties to a single propeties file loaded by it. But the question remains where were those properties being loaded from before ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how it was solved in our project, as the other answers didn't work for us. We were using spring batch, also.

main job config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MainJobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    PipelineConfig config;

    @Bean
    public PipelineConfig pipelineConfig(){
        return new PipelineConfig();
    }

    // To resolve ${} in @Value
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    // job stuff ...
}
```

properties config loader:

```
public class PipelineConfig {
    @Value("${option}")
    private boolean option;
}
```

Note how the `@Value` is in the PipelineConfig, but the actual properties from which the option is loaded, is specified in the job class.

Answer (score 1):

You even do not need a properties file, e.g.:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
```

Comment: Could you clarify where goes that line? In the xml of LookupManagerConfig? If I understood well, should it be equivalent to add `@Autowired PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer;` in LookupManagerConfig to use java config?

Comment: @jmmut obviously it would be applicationContext.xml !

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Framework 5.3.22 and Java 11 you can use straightforward declaration:

```java
@Value("${some.value}")
private boolean isSmth;
```

and corresponding property in `application.yaml`:

```yaml
some:
  value: true
```

Comment: I believe that it works, but can you provide a documentation reference for this syntax's support, in the latest Spring version?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson it looks like Spring official doc is quite outdated, at least as it is presented in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/value-annotations.html