# Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean]

Tags: java, spring

In a nutshell, Spring auto wiring failed on one field of my Java class.

I have a class which has a field set by Spring auto wiring. This field is of boolean type (not Boolean!). However, when unit testing it, I got an error saying,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${enable.pipe}] at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
```

The code is here,

```
@Value("${enable.pipe}")
private boolean isPipeEnabled;
```

This class runs well when loaded in a container, but failed and reports the error when running in a unit test. I've tried but failed to find a way to dump the value wired into.

Comment: the property file where "enable.pipe" is defined is not in the scope when the unit test runs.

Comment: I got another case where the field values are wired into via bean declaration.
`<bean id="sslContext" class="com.lab.Pipe1" scope="singleton">
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="pipe1.name" />
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="pipe1.pw" />
    </bean>`

I got a similar issue of field value null, and resolved it by adding the field in a property file.
`pipe1.pw=password`
However, in the case I did the same but did not work. One more difference is that the resolved one is from String to String I figure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating spring @value annotation as primitive boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585259/evaluating-spring-value-annotation-as-primitive-boolean)